# clik to load more data then click to hide then click load again does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a bit confused here.  I have a div which contains comments. Then when you click on the more comments icon, it calls php via ajax and appends the results to a div then slides it down. That part works fine. Then I have a hide icon which when you click on it, it collapses the expended div that was showing more comments. The problem, I am having is that if I collapse the div then click on show more comments again, the div no longer expands.

Below is the code which handles the more and hide clicks.  Any tips would be appreciated.. Thanks

```
 $("[id^='show_more_comments_']").on( 'click', function(e) {
       var pagenum     = $(this).data('newpage');
       var photoid     = $(this).data('photoid');
       var commentsdiv = 'morecomments_' + photoid;
       var moredots    = 'show_more_comments_' + photoid;
       var lessdots    = 'hide_more_comments_' + photoid;

       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "showmorecomments.php",
         data: {page: pagenum, photoid: photoid},

         success: function(data){
            $("#" + moredots).data('newpage', pagenum + 1);
            $("#" + lessdots).show();
            $(data).hide().appendTo("#" + commentsdiv).slideDown(500);
         }
       });
    });


 $("[id^='hide_more_comments_']").on( 'click', function(e) {
       var photoid     = $(this).data('photoid');
       var commentsdiv = 'morecomments_' + photoid;
       var moredots    = 'show_more_comments_' + photoid;
       var lessdots    = 'hide_more_comments_' + photoid;
       $("#" + commentsdiv).slideUp(500);
       $("#" + lessdots).hide();
       $("#" + moredots).data('newpage', 1);
       $("#" + moredots).data('photoid', photoid);
    });
```

If I set an alert to see the data values, they are correct. Its just no longer expanding the comments afyer I close them and try to open them again.

Thanks

JT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, slideUp hides the comments `div` so you must use a callback function to show the comments `div` again.

```
$("#" + commentsdiv).slideUp(500, function(){
  $(this).empty().show()
})
```

Check this code snippet:

```js
var data = '<div id="content">'
data += 'These are the comments to be added to the comment div'
data += '<ul>'
data += ' <li>Comment 1</li>'
data += ' <li>Comment 2</li>'
data += ' <li>Comment 3</li>'
data += '</ul>'
data += '</div>';

$(function() {
  $("#showBtn").click(function() {
    $(data).hide().appendTo("#morecomments_1").slideDown(500)
  })

  $("#hideBtn").click(function() {
    $("#morecomments_1").slideUp(500, function(){
      $(this).empty().show()
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="morecomments_1"></div>
<button id="showBtn">Show</button>
<button id="hideBtn">Hide</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just tried it. I lose the slide effect, it just pops up. But the problem still persists. after close i can no longer expand. even with your suggestion :(

Comment: That worked !!! Thanks !!! Can you explain something to me just for educational purpose :)  why can't i do this way. just curios whay it does not work like this        $("#" + commentsdiv).slideUp(500);
$("#" + commentsdiv).empty();
$("#" + commentsdiv).show();

Comment: `.slideUp` takes 500 milliseconds, and `.empty` will execute immediately, so you will lose the slide effect. This way you wait till the slideUp is complete, then empty and show it.